# How to install ubuntu on my Ipad?

Tags: ipad

Hello if anybody knows about first if is possible to install ubuntu explorer on ipad and how to do it.

Comment: What's ubuntu explorer?

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu explorer and no you can't install Ubuntu on an Ipad. If you bought an Ipad, you are stuck with ISO forever, it is the most locked down device you can buy.

Comment: Do you mean Nautilus File Explorer? Or Ubuntu's interface: Unity?

Comment: Ipod runs iOS, which is worse than Android, because Android is still linux (with a custom interface), but iOS is BSD. Some linux software runs well in BSD, and viceversa too, but i don't think anybody tried it on iOS, since iOS  software is all about profit, not about open-source and free sharing.

Comment: This may help you out with ditching IOS if that is your goal http://lifehacker.com/5693309/how-to-install-android-on-an-iphone-in-six-easy-steps but we can't give support here if you face issues ask about it at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

#### Short Answer

You can't. None of the applications typically associated with the Ubuntu desktop are available for iOS and Apple doesn't let you install your own software.

#### Long answer

According to [Mark's comment](/questions/780555/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-my-ipad#comment1168796_780555) it's possible to [install Android on iPads](http://lifehacker.com/5693309/how-to-install-android-on-an-iphone-in-six-easy-steps). Since Android is Linux it should be possible to build something that looks like the Ubuntu desktop and runs Ubuntu applications on top of it but it wouldn't actually be Ubuntu because it's based on Android. Hence the whole thing would be off topic here.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Comment: Yeah, if you could get Android working on an iPad, you might be able to use "Comlete Linux Installer" to install Ubuntu. That would pretty much be "real Ubuntu," right? It's basically using chroot or something to run Ubuntu on top of Android's Linux kernel?